# Aviso con mailto en Google Chrome

Tags: php, html

pues me a caido un prjecto web antiguo al que tengo que meterle SSL entre otras cosas. 
El problema es que la web tiene un form antiguo y su estructura es esta:

```
<form id="kontakt_form" action="mailto:info@kanzleizoeller.de" enctype="text/plain" method="get" target="_top">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="name" class="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="mail" class="text" name="E-Mail" placeholder="E-Mail" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="betreff" class="text" name="Betreff" placeholder="Betreff" type="text">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea id="nachricht" name="Nachricht" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>

            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="senden" class="btn-more" value="E-Mail senden" type="submit">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Y por supuesto se que el fallo esta en action="mailto:info@kanzleizoeller.de", pero no puedo generar un formulario nuevo por cuestiones de presupuesto al cliente, solo puedo repararlo, no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Envía el mail desde el servidor?

Comment: simplemente envia el mail desde tu server con php, son unas pocas lineas de codigo y no suponen un incremento en dinero para el cliente

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer puede ser tu amigo para enviar correos desde PHP.

Si vas a enviarlo desde el servidor del cliente necesitaras una cuenta válida en su servidor de correo; otra posibilidad es que utilices tu servidor de correo para enviar los correos.

Podrías hablar al cliente sobre DMARC y demostrarle cómo podría evitar en cierta medida suplantaciones de identidad.